# How to check if a string contains the characters from another string in Java?

Tags: java, string, character

I am using Java 8. Suppose I have two Strings `a=helloworld` and `b=howareyou` respectively. I want to find out the matching characters of String b from String a along with their position in b. As in my example the matching characters are `h`,`e`,`o`,`w`,`r` and `r` is the 5th character in string b. I don't want to find if it is the substring or not. I just want to check if the characters of one string are present in another string or not. Is there any way to do that? Below is my Java Code.

```
public class CharCheck {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "helloworld";
    String b = "howareyou";

    char st = containsAny(a, b);

    System.out.println(st+", ");
}

private static char containsAny(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1 == null || str1.length() == 0 || str2 == null || str2.length() == 0) {
        if (str1 == null || str1.length() == 0) {
            return 'X';
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str1.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
            if (str2.charAt(i) == ch) {
                return ch;
            }
        }
    }
    return 'X';
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: So you basically want to find which characters from String2 are contained in String1? What have you tried?

Comment: @CedricMartens: wrong language. This is Java, that question was about Javascript.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have edited my question. Please read it carefully. My question differs from other questions.

Comment: @CedricMartens My question is regarding `java` language and its not about finding substring.

Comment: Don't mark this question as duplicate until and unless you have read my question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not going to implement the solution for you but I'll give you the pusedocode.

```
for each letter1 in String1 
     for each letter2 in String2 
          if letter1 is letter2 then print its position
```

So you know you will need a nested for loop and a comparison, it becomes a bit more complicated if you want unique duplicates but i'll leave the rest up to you